# Bootstrap 3 align text to top

Tags: html, css

I am using the bootstrap framework and am having text that is being vertically centred in a column. I want to align text ( < p > ) to the top but not sure if there is a css for that

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align: top`.